# Magento 404 page in coming in admin panel for custom module

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module in admin panel. I ma getting 404 page. My module is active , but I am getting 404 page.

My config.xml file:

```
                            <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <config>
                  <modules>
                    <Blazedream_VendorComplaints>
                      <version>0.1.0</version>
                    </Blazedream_VendorComplaints>
                  </modules>
                  <frontend>
                    <routers>
                      <vendorcomplaints>
                        <use>standard</use>
                          <args>
                            <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
                            <frontName>vendorcomplaints</frontName>
                          </args>
                      </vendorcomplaints>
                    </routers>
                    <layout>
                          <updates>
                            <vendorcomplaints>
                              <file>vendorcomplaints.xml</file>
                            </vendorcomplaints>
                          </updates>
                    </layout>
                  </frontend>
                  <global>
                    <helpers>
                      <vendorcomplaints>
                        <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Helper</class>
                      </vendorcomplaints>
                    </helpers>
                    <blocks>
                      <vendorcomplaints>
                        <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Block</class>
                      </vendorcomplaints>
                    </blocks>
                    <models>
                      <vendorcomplaints>
                        <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model</class>
                        <resourceModel>vendorcomplaints_mysql4</resourceModel>
                      </vendorcomplaints>
                      <vendorcomplaints_mysql4>
                        <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Mysql4</class>
                        <entities>        
                              <complaints>
                                <table>vendor_complaints</table>
                              </complaints>
                        </entities>
                      </vendorcomplaints_mysql4>
                    </models>
                    <resources>
                      <vendorcomplaints_setup>
                        <setup>
                          <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                          <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                      </vendorcomplaints_setup>
                      <vendorcomplaints_write>
                        <connection>
                          <use>core_write</use>
                        </connection>
                      </vendorcomplaints_write>
                      <vendorcomplaints_read>
                        <connection>
                          <use>core_read</use>
                        </connection>
                      </vendorcomplaints_read>
                    </resources>

                  </global>
                  <admin>
                    <routers>
                      <vendorcomplaints>
                        <use>admin</use>
                        <args>
                          <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
                            <frontName>vendorcomplaints</frontName>
                        </args>
                      </vendorcomplaints>
                    </routers>
                  </admin>
                  <adminhtml>
                    <menu>
                      <marketplace>
                                <children>
                                    <vendorcomplaints module="vendorcomplaints">
                                    <title>Manage Complaints</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                    <action>admin_vendorcomplaints/adminhtml_complaints</action>
                                  </vendorcomplaints>
                                </children>
                            </marketplace>
                    </menu>
                     <acl>
                    <resources>
                        <all>
                        <title>Allow Everything</title>
                        </all>
                        <admin>
                            <children>
                                <vendorcomplaints>
                                    <title>Complaints Module</title>
                                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                                </vendorcomplaints>
                            </children>
                        </admin>
                    </resources>
                </acl>
                    <layout>
                      <updates>
                        <vendorcomplaints>
                          <file>vendorcomplaints.xml</file>
                        </vendorcomplaints>
                      </updates>
                    </layout>
                  </adminhtml>
                </config>
```

I dont know where i had done mistake. Can anyone help me to fix this.?
I am new to magento.

Comment: logout and login again. this issue will be resolved

Comment: Try admin panel logout login again

Comment: I did. still i ma getting the same.

Comment: it happen if anything is wrong in acl

Comment: Yes, You are right.. I got 404 because for Acl only.  I had given wrongly..

Comment: I have corrected now.. Thanks @chanz

Answer (score 0):

first you should learn custom module.

have a look on these blogs.
[create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/) 
[custom_magento_system_configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)

According to your code you might miss the ACL implementation.